# Icloud deleting photos when trying to sync with pc

Tags: icloud, photos, pc

I'm trying to help my friend backup her entire photocollection 25k+ images from Icloud. However her macbook pro mid 2012 has a history of crashing so we thought we might use my win 10 pc instead. I downloaded the Icloud program, signed in and selected a folder to sync all the pictures to. Sometime during the syncing process i got the message: "The files have been deleted from iCloud Photos on all your devices and moved to the Recently Deleted folder on Apple devices. You will have 30 days to recover them."

I proceeded to terminate the process and recover the 8 photos that had been moved. Why would this happen and what can i do to stop it if i want to sync the photos?

The plan now is to either *try* and use her macbook or download everything from privacy.apple